# Ansible extract GCP disk type

Tags: ansible

I have a short test playbook that I use to retrieve a GCP disk type:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    gcp_cred_kind: serviceaccount
    gcp_cred_file: /etc/ansible/keys/ansible-stl-production-service-account-key.json

  tasks:  

  - name: get info on boot disk
    gcp_compute_disk_info:
      zone: us-central1-c
      filters:
      - name = server-data-disk
      project: <my GCP project>
      auth_kind: serviceaccount
      service_account_file: /etc/ansible/keys/ansible-stl-production-service-account-key.json
    register: target_server_disk_reg

  - debug:
      var:    
        target_boot_disk_reg.resources[0].type

  - set_fact:
      new_disk_type: "{{ target_boot_disk_reg.resources[0].type | regex_replace('^https://www.googleapis.com/.*/.*/.*/.*/.*/.*/(.+)$','\\1') }}"
```

The output of the gcp_compute_disk_info looks like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<my GCP project>/zones/us-central1-c/diskTypes/pd-standard
```

I want to extract pd-standard from this output. But the regex_replace does not work.

How do I set the correct string to retrieve the disk type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There was a missing ) at the end of the regex_replace. After add ) to the string, the playbook worked!

Comment: If it is a simple typo you should close the question.